# Creating a new instance of another file

Tags: php

I have a php file called index which is the entry point for my api with the following code

```
//Entry point...
try {
    echo (new requestHandler($_REQUEST['request'], $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']))->DoStuff();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(Array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
}
```

Then the requestHandler.php handles the request

```
public function __construct($request)
{
     echo "constructor";
     //do some things
}
```

However when i call index.php it seems to give an error

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'requestHandler' not found in .../index.php`

Note: both are separate files...

Comment: Do you have an autoloader configured or at least `require_once 'path/to/file/with/requestHandler.php'`? Also, you appear to be passing two arguments to the `requestHandler` constructor where it only takes one.

Comment: @Phil sorry my knowledge is limited in php however am i supposed to require the file ? or there are some better ways ?

Comment: Well, for class loading, I will always recommend an autoloader (see [Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.autoload.php)) but it all comes down to including / requiring the file containing the class definition.

Comment: so @Phil can you throw an answer with a basic example of Autoloading that works in my case ?

Comment: No, because I don't know where your files are, relative to each other

Comment: @Phil those 2 files are in the same folder... i tried to add the __autoload function but it gives me an error in the php log `failed to open stream`

Comment: Obviously you didn't read that page very carefully ~ *"spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for autoloading classes. For this reason, **using __autoload() is discouraged** and may be deprecated or removed in the future."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, I suggest you simply add this to the top of your *index* script...

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/requestHandler.php';
```

This is of course assuming the `requestHandler` class is defined in a file named `requestHandler.php`.

If you want to try using an autoloader, you need to stick to a convention of class to file names. In your case, it seems like this should suffice (again, in your *index* script)...

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $path = sprintf('%s/%s.php', __DIR__, $class);
    if (is_readable($path)) {
        require $path;
    }
});
```